# grails gorm executeQuery HQL inner join

Tags: hql, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-controller, executequery

I am trying to do a simple inner join using GORM's executeQuery but getting a QuerySyntaxException.....I believe my hql is ok. Here is my query

```
def query = Institution.executeQuery("select longName from Institution inner join TacticalIndustryCode.idInstitution")
log.info(query.size())
```

I tried this with same error too:

```
def query = Institution.executeQuery("from Institution inner join TacticalIndustryCode.id")
```

Here is my exception that I am receiving

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'null.idInstitution' [select longName from erebus.industryGroup.Institution inner join TacticalIndustryCode.idInstitution]
    at erebus.industryGroup.TacticalIndustryCodeController$$ENunaZiV.list(TacticalIndustryCodeController.groovy:20)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: you need to read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a field called '`idInstitution`' in the domain '`TacticalIndustryCode`'.

Remember that when you write HQLs, you don't refer to the table or its columns. Instead you use the mapped class and their properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
def query = Institution.executeQuery("select inst.longName from Institution as inst inner join inst.tacticalIndustryCode")
```

For more info follow the link:
http://grails.asia/grails-hql-join-examples